# Connection timeout using nodejs stompit when connecting to activemq artemis

Tags: node.js, stomp, activemq-artemis

I am making stompit connection to my ActiveMQ Artemis broker and I see no error when calling connect. After some time (in few mins) I see Connection timeout error.

Also, I am not seeing the queue being created (only address) getting created and the message is not seen at the Artemis console.

[image]

ActiveMQ Artemis console:

[image]

Code:

```js
const stompConnectOptions= {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 61613,
    'connectHeaders': {
        'host': '/', 'login': 'admin', 'passcode': 'xxxx', 'heart-beat': '1000,1000'
    }
};

const stompit=require ('stompit') const subscribeHeaders= {
    'destination': 'emailEvent', 'ack': 'client-individual'
};

const sendHeaders= {
    'destination': '/queue/TestEvent', 'content-type': 'text/plain'
};

stompit.connect(stompConnectOptions, (err, client)=> {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error with stomp connection.");
        return;
    }
    console.log("stomp connected") stompClient=client;
    const frame=client.send(sendHeaders);
    frame.write('hello');
    frame.end();
    console.log('hello message sent')
});
```

ActiveMQ server logs:

[image]

```
2020-01-29 23:33:46,333 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp] AMQ332069: Sent ERROR frame to STOMP client /127.0.0.1:52170: null
2020-01-29 23:33:46,334 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222067: Connection failure has been detected: null [code=REMOTE_DISCONNECT]
2020-01-29 23:33:46,335 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 21617631-4319-11ea-a1bd-24a2e1f3b27a
2020-01-29 23:33:46,337 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 21617631-4319-11ea-a1bd-24a2e1f3b27a
```

I am new to stompit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ActiveMQ Artemis STOMP documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html) should be helpful here.

The first thing I recommend is enabling debug logging. [The documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html#logging) states:

> Incoming and outgoing STOMP frames can be logged by enabling `DEBUG` for `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp.StompConnection`. This can be extremely useful for debugging or simply monitoring client activity. Along with the STOMP frame itself the remote IP address of the client is logged as well as the internal connection ID so that frames from the same client can be correlated.

You can enable this logging by modifying `etc/logging.properties`.

**First**, add this to the comma-separated `loggers` list at the beginning of the file:

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp.StompConnection
```

**Second**, add a new line with this under the `ActiveMQ Artemis logger levels` comment:

```
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp.StompConnection.level=DEBUG
```

Once you have the logging enabled it should help you see why the connection is being closed. My guess is that the client is not sending the proper heart-beating frames. In that case you can try connecting with no heartbeat, e.g.:

```
const stompConnectOptions= {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 61613,
    'connectHeaders': {
        'host': '/', 'login': 'admin', 'passcode': 'xxxx', 'heart-beat': '0,0'
    }
};
```

The documentation should also help explain why only an address is being created and not a queue as well. [In the "Sending" section](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html#sending) the documentation states:

> When a STOMP client sends a message (using a `SEND` frame), the protocol manager looks at the message to determine where to route it and potentially how to create the address and/or queue to which it is being sent. The protocol manager uses either of the following bits of information from the frame to determine the routing type:
>
> 1. The value of the `destination-type` header. Valid values are `ANYCAST` and `MULTICAST` (case sensitive).
> 2. The "prefix" on the `destination` header. See [additional info](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#using-prefixes-to-determine-routing-type) on prefixes.
>
> If no indication of routing type is supplied then the default defined in the corresponding `default-address-routing-type` & `default-queue-routing-type` address-settings will be used.
>
> The `destination` header maps to an address of the same name. If the `destination` header used a prefix then the prefix is stripped.

When you send your message the broker is using the `MULTICAST` routing type which means it will only auto-create the address and not a queue. This is the default behavior.

As noted in the documentation **you have 3 main options** to resolve this...

**One**, you can send the `destination-type` header, e.g.:

```
const sendHeaders= {
    'destination': '/queue/TestEvent', 'content-type': 'text/plain', 'destination-type': 'ANYCAST'
};
```

**Two**, you can configure a prefix on the STOMP `acceptor` like is done in the ["stomp-jms" example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/examples/protocols/stomp/stomp-jms/src/main/resources/activemq/server0/broker.xml#L32) shipped with the broker, e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?anycastPrefix=/queue/</acceptor>
```

**Three**, you can change the default routing types via address-settings, e.g.:

```xml
<address-setting match="#">
   ...
   <default-address-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-address-routing-type>
   <default-queue-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-queue-routing-type>
   ...
</address-setting>
```

Of course, using a `match` of `#` will change the default for *every* address & queue so you may want to tune that for your specific needs.

Comment: thanks for your post, it helped me understand and fix why queue not creating issue. The connection issue is not happening anymore not sure how it resolved. will continue to check thanks

Comment: connected failed just now.

Comment: 2020-01-30 19:54:24,734 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp.StompConnection] STOMP(/192.168.0.10:50538, b5d4fe43):OUT >> StompFrame[command=ERROR, headers={message=null}, content= null, bytes= null
2020-01-30 19:54:24,738 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.stomp] AMQ332069: Sent ERROR frame to STOMP client /192.168.0.10:50538: null
2020-01-30 19:54:24,739 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222067: Connection failure has been detected: null [code=REMOTE_DISCONNECT]

Comment: Are you still connecting with `'heart-beat': '1000,1000'`? Also, you'll need to provide debug logs from the entire time the Stomp connection was active so I can see what was happening. At this point I suspect the client is closing its connection without sending a `DISCONNECT` frame.

Comment: still with heart-beat :1000.